# Run Crystal Reports on client machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

My C# application using Crystal Reports. I would like to run my application on client machine. After googling, I know that client machine must install Crystal Reports runtime package.

Do I have any other solution? Can I attach Crystal Reports dll files in my running folder to solve this?

Hope this make sense

Thank you in advance and Happy New Year 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the tests I did after some reading, we need to download appropriate version of runtime client MSI installers for 64 bit or 32 bit machines as applicable from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 
This needs to be installed separately.
I also tried setting up the prerequisite for the installer however it does not work as expected.

Comment: Is this a solution to the question above ?

Comment: As per my tests that I did, there is no way other than installing the separate client runtime package as it does not work with just set of dlls in the application folder. I cannot say this is the solution to the question above, but this is the only way that I can see SAP Crystal Reports working.

Comment: ah Ok. I just didn't know if you were posing a question. Sorry. And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

change the property of all reports `.rpt` files , set `build action from Embedded Resource` to `Content` and then copy all  `.rpt` and `.cs` files of my reports in the same setup folder , so it will run  on client machine too.

Comment: built action of "Embedded Resource" or "Content" will ensure report files presence on the client machine. However the question here is what about the assemblies required to run the reports in client information. Is there any way to make those part of the deployment package?